# Create a relationship - SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, relationship

I have a table called `Match_Details` and another one called `Team`

`Match_Details` columns:

[image]

`Team` columns:

[image]

In each row of `Match_Details` I have **one** championship name and **two** teams name. In `Team` each row include championship name and one team name, creating a UNIQUE entry for each team in each championship. I'm aiming to create a link between this to tables. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Have you look at foreign keys? *Also, SSMS 2017 isn't the version of your SQL Server. SSMS interacts with a SQL Server instance. but it isn't SQL Server itself. SSMS 2017 works against SQL Server 2008-2017, which means you *could* be using one of 6 different versions.*

Comment: i link both tables using `Champion_Name` but i want to go to the lower level which is `Team`.

Comment: Check [Create Foreign Key Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017) in the docs

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2015 (or SSMS 2015) - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick ....

Comment: What is `Champion_Name_Team_Name`? It looks like something redundant, since you already have `Champion_Name` and `Team_Name`. You can have a compound primary key. In `Match_Details`, `Championship_Name` + `Home_Team_Name` would form one foreign key, `Championship_Name` + `Away_Team_Name` would form the other. However, what seems to be missing here is `Championship` itself and/or a `Team` table that does not have `Champion_Name`. Why would team names vary per championship, or the team identity be linked to the championship?

Comment: `Champion_Name_Team_Name` is the primary key (Championship name & Team name) for each row because we may have teams with the same name in different championship.

Comment: I think you are missing a Championship/Tournament table here.